# alignParentRight make the layout take parent's width despite being 'wrap content' in chat bubble

Tags: android, layout

I am tryign to create a chat bubble like this -

[image: this image]

But I want this bubble to wrap its content.
Now problem is that whenever I try to use 'alignparentRight = true" to those 'double-ticks', it expands to view to take up whole parents width.

How could I make it wrap the its content where ticks stay at right bottom and text 'hero' stays on top left.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bubble_send"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chat_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/chat_comment"
        android:src="@drawable/rotate"
        android:visibility="visible"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chat_comment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/time"
        android:maxWidth="200dp"
        android:text="Hero"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tick"

        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tick"
        android:text="11:25 am"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="10sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tick"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chat_comment"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_tick_double"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to avoid multiple nesting, but this was the only resort. -

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bubble_send"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chat_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/chat_comment"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/rotate"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chat_comment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/time"
            android:maxWidth="200dp"
            android:text="Hero"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tick"
            android:text="11:25 am"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="10sp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tick"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_tick_double"
            android:visibility="visible"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/wrapper"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/bubble_send"
android:gravity="right"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/chat_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/chat_comment"
    android:src="@drawable/rotate"
    android:visibility="visible"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/chat_comment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/time"
    android:maxWidth="200dp"
    android:text="Hero"
    android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tick"

    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tick"
    android:text="11:25 am"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="10sp"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tick"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/chat_comment"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_tick_double"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

-**Instead of making your main layout to wrap content put it as fixed width**

Comment: putting fixed width is not a good idea provided all the fragmentation we have in Android. That's why I spent last evening getting around this issue.